# Find procedure respond time on database last 30 day

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there any way to find out the duration of store procedure respond in last 30 day or more ?
i have a program that running store procedure on server and some days this sp stops responding or takes too long to respond(need Instance to restart).

now i need to find out why and when this happen.
my guess is there is a some Concurrent sp that locks the table and stop this sp from running.

Comment: Try looking at the `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats` management view - it won't cover 30 days, but it might be useful.

Comment: @Bridge im trying it now and it returned last_execution_time.
i guess i can use that to check few minute after and few minute before of my sp run time with this table to find out the concurrent Situation.
thanks for suggestion